# Does a writing website promoting commissions count as commercial/do I need an impressum? (Freelancer according to Germany's laws)

Tags: freelance-websites, freelance, writing

According to Germany's (and other countries varying) Telemedia Act(s), commercial websites must include an Impressum. I am freelancing in the writing industry, so I am a freelancer and not a tradesperson (any profession not counted as freelancing under German law).

For this reason, my website does not offer any direct commercial activity, such as giving up orders or entering any sort of financial details. My page, theoretically, only lists prices and methods to contact me directly. Does this page, therefore, count as commercial in the sense of the Telemedia Act and therefore require an Impressum, including my VAT ID number and my registered business address? I'd prefer to leave that out and remain anonymous.

As it is, I haven't been to the tax office to get those documents, as making my freelancing official would burden me with expenses. You see, I am doing this pretty small-scope, so I wouldn't have to pay taxes according to our laws (Kleingewerbe Regelung), but I would have to pay insurance, which far outstrips my very irregular and very low earnings (<100€/Month). The reason why I would have to pay insurance is because of my particular circumstances. More specifically, I am registered as unemployed (Arbeitslos), so my writing would technically be my primary income source as far as I can tell and, therefore, require me to pay those insurances monthly.

I plan to get together with a tax consultant in the future before committing hard to anything, but I was just wondering about the commercial/non-commercial website governing. Any help is greatly appreciated.